# FileNotFoundException while converting imgUrl to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an image manager class which handles converting a string of imageUrl into a bitmap, with which I will use to upload the image onto server. It throws a FileNotFoundException while I run the code. Could anyone please have a look what's the problem? Thanks!

ImageManager Class:

```
public class ImageManager {

private static final String TAG = "ImageManager";

public static Bitmap getBitmap(String imgUrl){
    File imageFile = new File(imgUrl);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try{

        fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getBitmap: FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());

    }finally {
        try{
            fis.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getBitmap: IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Logs:

```
E/ImageManager: getBitmap: FileNotFoundException: file: /data/user/0/mypackage/cache/cropped12644.jpg: open failed: EN0EN...
```

I have tested the new file using below codes. Both returned as false.

```
Log.d(TAG, "testing file: " + imageFile.exists());
Log.d(TAG, "testing file: " + imageFile.canRead());
```

I got the imageUrl from a cropped image which is correctly showing up in an imageView in my ConfirmPhoto Activity code as below:

```
public class ConfirmPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ConfirmPhotoActivity";


//widgets
private SquareImageView squareImageView;
private ImageView backarrow;
private TextView confirm_photo;

//vars
private String imageUrl;
private int imageCount = 0;

//firebase
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private FirebaseMethods mFirebaseMethods;
private String userID;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting confirm photo activity.");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_photo);
    mFirebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(this);


    squareImageView = findViewById(R.id.confirm_photo_imageView);
    backarrow = findViewById(R.id.back_button_imageView);
    confirm_photo = findViewById(R.id.confirm_photo);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra("croppedImageUrl");



    setupFirebaseAuth();
    setImage();
    enableBack();
    uploadImage();


}

private void setImage(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setImage: setting up the image.");
    UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imageUrl, squareImageView, "");
}

private void uploadImage(){

    confirm_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto("new_photo", imageCount, imageUrl);

        }
    });

}


private void enableBack() {
    backarrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: closing activity.");
            finish();
        }
    });
}

 /*
---------------------------------- firebase --------------------------------------
 */


private void setupFirebaseAuth() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth.");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: image count: " + imageCount);
    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: signed_in" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: signed_out");
                Intent intent = new Intent(ConfirmPhotoActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            imageCount = mFirebaseMethods.getImageCount(dataSnapshot);
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: image count: " + imageCount);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post where `imgUrl` comes from

Comment: where do you get `String imgUrl` from? from some `android.net.Uri`? post your code where you are using `getBitmap(String imgUrl)`

Comment: just added the code where I got the url from. It's actually passed over from a crop image activity to my ConfirmPhoto activity. And I can get the image correctly display in my imageView. And when I am trying to upload the image using a Firebase method that's when I use this getBitmap method..

Comment: so if `UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imageUrl, ...` works then what is the content of `imageUrl` here?

Comment: content here is what I got from the crop image activity. so a cropped image which I picked from my gallery and cropped.

Comment: what do you see on the logcat when you call `Log.d(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);` just after `imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra("croppedImageUrl");` ? and after `UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imageUrl, squareImageView, "");` ?

Comment: I figured it out... I found that the imageUrl I got somehow contains these characters at front "file:". So I deleted these characters from the url when making the new file and now everything works. Thanks anyway!